# R.java not generated for android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using eclipse and the `R.java` file is not being generated. I understand from other discussions that this may be a problem due to an incorrect layout content. Here is my layout file generated by the SDK. I am not sure what the error is.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/first_android_app" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't Eclipse show any error markers here? (The only thing I notice, is a missing </RelativeLayout> in your snippet)

Comment: Did you try clean+build?

Comment: Verify if you have automatic building in project menu. Have you an eclipse error log for that?

Comment: The "problems" tab in your eclipse window will tell you why it didn't create it.

Comment: @user1918149 : update something in layout.. save and clean it..

Answer (score 1):

Please see your resource file there will be some error in your XML file or name of images in capital latter .once its fix then clean the project and run.

Answer (score 0):

Try clean and build or use IntelliJ IDEA for Android developing :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any mistakes here, try to clean and restart Eclipse. It could also be that you have imported files with capital letters or any other characters that are not supported. Please be more clear because this is not going to help you out. What else did you do before this problem occured? What is the error message you see?

Answer (score 0):

**Reasons** for missing R.java could be

- When you dont properly name your drawables
- When there is some issue with your layouts
- When you forget to register things (Activity etc) in AndroidManifest
  file
- When there is a conflict in package name in manifest and some other
  place
- Sometimes multiple pacakges can arise this issue

**Tip:
Look at the error in the console and see where does it refer !!**

**Fact:**
Cleaning the project does not solve the problem always

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

Open a terminal window and type

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

even if you are using a 64-bit os, this will again help you. It worked perfectly for me.